# How do I auto-resize dimensions for a named google sheet

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

My Java Google Sheet API method to auto-resize dimensions of a Google sheet is working but only on the default sheet that had `gid = 0`. A particular `spreadsheetId` that identifies a Google Sheet can have several tabs each with a particular `gid`.

I wish to only target a particular sheet with a different `gid` than `gid = 0` when I auto-resize dimensions. How do I adjust my code for that to happen?

```
public static void setAutoResizeDimensions(String spreadsheetId, int startindex, int endindex) throws IOException {

    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    AutoResizeDimensionsRequest autoResizeDimensions = new AutoResizeDimensionsRequest();
    DimensionRange dimensions = new DimensionRange().setDimension("COLUMNS").setStartIndex(startindex).setEndIndex(endindex);

    requests.add(new Request()
            .setAutoResizeDimensions(autoResizeDimensions
                    .setDimensions(dimensions)));


    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
            .setRequests(requests);
    SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
            .execute();
}
```

I'm currently using the following version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev21-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Regards,
Conteh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the gid by inspecting each sheet and confirming if that is the sheet that has to be modified either by looking at title or any field value:
You can do that by:

```
Get get = SHEETS.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId);
Spreadsheet file = sheets.execute();
Sheet sheetToUpdate=null;
for(Sheet sheet: file.getSheets()){
   int index = sheet.getProperties().getIndex();
   //if this is the sheet you want to update
   sheetToUpdate = sheet;
}
int gid = sheetToUpdate.getProperties.getSheetId();
```

Once you have the gid you can use the code in the update block to update that specific sheet within the spreadsheet.

**Update:**

If you know the gid you can pass the gid as an argument as

```
DimensionRange dimensions = new DimensionRange().setDimension("COLUMNS")
.setStartIndex(0).setEndIndex(2).setSheetId(gidNum);
```

Comment: ,,, I'm trying the code out what version are you using here.. I'm currently on v4-rev21-1.22.0

Comment: ,, I upgraded to version v4-rev476-1.22.0 still not seeing the  file.getSheets() method.. will try the latest version..

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version v4-rev478-1.22.0 still not seeing the getSheets() method. I get "incompatible types: Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get cannot be converted to Spreadsheet" on Spreadsheet file = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);

Comment: @conteh Sorry for the confusion, We had our own API overriding some of the functionalities to provide abstraction over Google's API, so there was a confusion, please look at the current answer.

Answer (score 0):

autoResizeColumn(columnPosition) See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumn(Integer))

Sets the width of the given column to fit its contents

```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

     sheet.getRange('a1').setValue('Whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul...');

 // Sets the first column to a width which fits the text
 sheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
```

You can combine that with the Activate info [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate()) to see how to get sheet by name.

```
 // This example assumes there is a sheet named "first"
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
 first.activate();
```

You can use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow) and [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastColumn()) to expand range to all of data in sheet. 
Finally combine this with [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()) if you so desire. But all numeric values also work for range. See below.

So we end up with something like this.:

```
 var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ssa.getSheetByName(name);
 var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var range =  sheet.getRange(1,1, lastCol, lastRow);
 range.Activate();
 for (i = 1; i <= lastCol;i++) {
   sheet.autoResizeColumn(i);
 }
```